# Service Stack Kill a HTTP request in filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, servicestack

Is there a way to kill an HTTPRequest inside of a filter. I the following code:

```
this.RequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) =>
{                
    var access_token = req.Headers.GetValues("token");
    if(access_token == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(access_token[0]))
    {
        //Kill Request here, ensuring it does not hit the service and returns an unauthorized       error code
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't throwing an exception stop the request?

Comment: Wow, well that was easier than I though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rosdi was correct the answer is to do the following:

```
this.RequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) =>
{                
    var access_token = req.Headers.GetValues("token");
    if(access_token == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(access_token[0]))
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to throw an exception there's no need to set the status code, as a `503 Forbidden` status code will automatically be set on the response for `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Comment: Edited to refelct that commen @mythz

Answer (score 3):

Use `EndRequest()` to end the request and short-circuit the request pipeline, e.g:

```
this.RequestFilters.Add((req, res, requestDto) =>
{                
    var access_token = req.Headers.GetValues("token");
    if (access_token == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(access_token[0]))
        res.EndRequest()
}
```